# NGINX reverse proxy to a URL that requires the sub-domain

Tags: nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy

I use a third-party web app that has assigned a custom sub-domain to my company. Let's call it http://mycompany.blogsite.com. I do not have any control over blogsite.com, the ports, or my custom sub-domain.

I'm trying to make this accessible on http://mycompany.com/blog/, using NGINX as a reverse proxy.

It returns a 403 or 404 when I visit http://mycompany.com/blog/, which leads me to believe it's not passing the required sub-domain to the remote server - either the subdomain or the path must (?) be getting mangled somehow.

Here's what my config looks like presently, though I've tried several different variations of this:

```
location /blog/ {
    proxy_pass http://mycompany.blogsite.com;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host  $host;
}
```

Currently, I am testing everything with http, and the remote server does allow it. Eventually I'll need to add ssl, but I figure I'll get this working, first.

Thank you for any pointers!

Comment: How about `proxy_pass http://mycompany.blogsite.com/;` ?. But also i wonder if they do anything with the Host header, so maybe try commenting that line out as well and test like that too.More info about the trailing slash [in the nginx docs](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_pass) - look for `A request URI is passed to the server as follows:`

Comment: Thanks, it's closer to working! The page starts loading, but several JS resources at the original URL `http://mycompany.blogsite.com/{folder}/{file}` 404 at the proxied URL `http://mycompany.com/blog/{folder}/{file}`. I thought it might be a CORS issue, and added what I found at https://enable-cors.org/server_nginx.html, but it didn't seem to affect it.

Comment: Getting closer... `The script from “http://mycompany.com/blog/jquery/jquery-ui.min.js” was loaded even though its MIME type (“text/html”) is not a valid JavaScript MIME type.`  -- I'm looking into setting the X-Content-Type-Options headers now.

Comment: I've now loaded cert-bot and added https to everything, and it has fixed some of this... but the page still does not completely load, it hangs on an animated loading gif. I'm getting two messages that I do not get on the original site, `Warning: You cannot PUSH the same path using hash history` and `SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data`

Comment: The MIME error: does that show up on when you go directly `mycompany.blogsite.com` as well? Cause that is their problem to fix. As far as the PUSH and JSON.parse errors, those are javascript errors caused most likely by a script that was not loaded correctly or depended on a script that is not loading for some reason.

Answer (score 2):

It Should be simple as this:

```
 location /blog/ {
   proxy_pass http://mycompany.blogsite.com/;
    }
```